# Add extra properties to an object?

Tags: powershell

I want to get a list of files in a specific location from a list of remote computers. I want  the output to have the File Name, Last Write Time and the Computer's Name that it's from.

The  properties of the files don't include a computer name. So how could I build the file list including the computername in the output?

`$serverlist = Get-Content c:\jasonbe\Serverlist.txt
foreach ($server in $serverlist)
{Get-ChildItem '\\server\c$\location\Ultimate\Retail\Bin\' | Select Name, LastWriteTime, Length
Get-ChildItem '\\server\c$\location\Ultimate\Retail\Reports\*.rpt' | Select Name, LastWriteTime, Length
}`

Hope I make sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the select like this:

```
Select Name, LastWriteTime, Length,  {$server}
```

Comment: I could give you a kiss. Thanks!